# UITableView Header Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I stopped development of my app for a couple months, and now I'm coming back to it. For the life of me, I can't remember how I got the UITableView Header to be larger:
[image]

I'm trying to get it to go back to a normal table view (not such a huge header). I checked through my code, and there's no mention of "header" anywhere. Am I missing something in the Storyboard inspector? Is there a way to reset the attributes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Select your table view in your storyboard or nib file. In the Utilities side bar, go to the size tab (selected in the screenshot) and check the Section Height options.

Does that help?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I have it set at 1, and still no luck.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to just delete that table view and just readd a table view/reconnect the connections?

Comment: This is really weird. I deleted it and put in a new UITableView. Before connecting it to any code, it had the same header margin as shown in my question. Interesting... (thanks for your help by the way!!)

Comment: That's really weird, could you try creating a new view controller completely off to the side and putting a table view in it? Also click the view controller itself and check the attributes tab in the right side bar. Make sure "Under Opaque Bars" is unchecked in the Extend Edges section.

Comment: Light bulb! I didn't have it stretched all the way to the top of the view, so that it could go under the view's header. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It hope it should work by just setting the frame property of the `UITableView` header.

```
CGRect newFrame = myHeaderView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height + 100;
myHeaderView.frame = newFrame;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myHeaderView;
```